# Conditional assignments in bash

Tags: bash, zsh

In `bash` (and `zsh`), how do I most concisely assign the value of `$1` to
the variable `w`, if `$1` is given, and otherwise a default
value `4`?

I tried

```
w=$(( $1 != "" ? $1 : 4))
```

but that returned an error message.

Is there anything simpler than

```
w=4; [[ $1 != "" ]] && w=$1
```

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that you tagged the question with `bash` but quote a `zsh` error message ...

Comment: @AdminBee, sorry.  but i'd prefer something that works in both.

Comment: I understand. You may want to edit your question to point that out, though, it might attract "bashisms" otherwise ;) (there, I used a new word I learned recently!)

Answer (score 8):

Use a parameter expansion of the form `${parameter:-word}`

> `${parameter:-word}` Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

```
w=${1:-4}
```

---

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.

```
w=${1-4}
```